# TranslateTransform.BeginAnimation in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a working WPF application that would like to port to SilverLight. I have a piece of WPF code that I haven't found a way to mimic in SilverLight.

**WPF Code Snippet:**

TranslateTransform trans = null;

> trans = child.RenderTransform as
>   TranslateTransform;
>
> trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty,
>   new DoubleAnimation(curX,
>   animationLength),
>   HandoffBehavior.Compose);

The problem is the BeginAnimation call. it doesn't appear to exist on the TranslateTransform object. Any ideas how I can accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeginAnimation doesn't exist in Silverlight. You could use a Storyboard instead